# How to add custom css inside shadow DOM in ionic 4?

Tags: css, ionic4, shadow-dom

I have this html code:

```
<ion-content>
    <section class='container'>
        ....
    </section>
</ion-content>
```

I just want the content to be centered on the screen, so I added this css on the inspector first.

I targeted the main element and it worked.

[image]

Now, I added this css to the scss file of the page.

```
main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

But the css doesn't work. Is there any way I can add the custom css on the `<main>` inside ion-content shadow root?

Please help. I'm stuck at this.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I solved using this one.

```
ion-content::part(scroll) {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

But if you guys have better idea, just share it. Thank you!